# PhpMyAdmin table does not exist

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a new table in a database (from the sql code of a backup) but whenever I submit the code it simply says that the table does not exist(yes, trying to create it so of course it doesn't exist yet). Also when I try to make any table at all, it submits without error but the table is not created. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read your question again and think deeply, what kind of information do you think we need to help you fix your SQL query? :p

Comment: I don't think it's the query itself. I exported the table before and entered it in another phpmyadmin without any errors at all. Also (as described in the question), no matter what I submit (even in the table creation form and yes, I am very used to SQL) no table at all is created.

Comment: No errors at all? Do you have the rights to `create table`? Do you get the 'table does not exist' error when you try to create the table, or when you try to use it afterwards?

Comment: When I submit the SQL backup code itself then I get that error *tables does not exist* indeed! And except for that, I'm the root user and I have always had this setup but this is the first time something like this happens

Comment: My guess is that the message comes from other statements in your script, for instance statements that try to add an index or insert records. That could mean there is an error in the create table statement, or it is missing. But apart from that, there is not much I can do to help. "It always works and now it doesn't" isn't the kind of problem that has a generic answer, especially if we can't see the script that suddenly doesn't work.

Comment: This is my script: 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Diary` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `U_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Title` text NOT NULL,
  `Content` text NOT NULL,
  `Password` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;